# Ubuntu installation , problems with partitions .. What i need to do?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

Using Rufus to create bootable image on mine windows 10 
(The OS came with the laptop from the store) . 
Laptop model Lenovo Y720 ..

1. I tried to create MBR/GPT partition schema with ISO mode (recomended) .
2. I tried to create MBR/GPT partition schema with DD mode

3.The modes i tried to load mine usb and maybe overcome this problem , UEFI and Legacy .

The OS Ubuntu is up and running in all 3 cases ..

But when it come to partitions here it begins .

No root file system , well Ok i am trying to make one but , it won't let me for example . If i choose the 512 000MB partition creation it create for me only 1MB partition and 0MB partition . 
The problem is that i can't create any partition with volume i need and set it to root .. I tried anything + ext4 filesystem format .

Does anybody had this kind of problem ?

I got last Ubuntu version LTS downloaded today from their site .

The strange thing is that , on mine second laptop i tried to install Kali Linux and it required from me the DD mode for the OS image in order to work , but for this case i have no idea what i need to do ..

Mine home PC has Ubuntu installed exactly the same version and working good.

After trying to install another OS BackBox , i got the stack error when i moving during installation to the Installation type stage,
when i click on change or '+' buttons in the menu to add or change partitions as above
i got this errors: For Ubuntu problem i don't have any stack trace ..

> > Installer crashed :
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >     File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-partman.py",line 1293 in on_partition_list_new active self_.partman_dialog(devpart,partition)
> >     File "usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/plugin.py",line 48,in wrapper , return target (self,*args,**kwargs,)
> >     File "usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-partman.py",line 956, in partman_dialog
> >     Type_Error:'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

The USB flashing is your problem? If yes than i suggest using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).
It's really easy to use and does a great job. Only thing it'll take all the space on the USB, you can't flash just a partition like in Rufus.

Comment: Ok so there another program  , but how it will help me ? Are you saying that all the pain because of Rufus (I using it every time and it worked ) ?

Comment: I tried,and got the same result ..

Comment: Seems i misunderstood your question, your problem is while installing Ubuntu? Ar you trying to install Kali, Ubuntu dekstop or server?

Comment: Desktop , i will update mine question with new information above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop as you. Basically I opened disk management in windows 10, created an empty partition for example 100g on my SSD, and then made a new partition on that. Then I booted into the Ubuntu installation, and chose custom install. I then chose that 100gb from the custom install.

Here is the help I followed:

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Btw. remember to disable fast boot and secure boot in BIOS.